# Running Django's collectstatic in Dockerfile produces empty directory

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to run Django from a Docker container on Heroku, but to make that work, I need to run `python manage.py collectstatic` during my build phase. To achieve that, I wrote the following Dockerfile:

```
# Set up image
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install poetry and identify Python dependencies
RUN pip install poetry
COPY pyproject.toml /usr/src/app/

# Install Python dependencies
RUN set -x \
    && apt update -y \
    && apt install -y \
        libpq-dev \
        gcc \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-ansi

# Copy source into image
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Collect static files
RUN python -m manage collectstatic -v 3 --no-input
```

And here's the docker-compose.yml file I used to run the image:

```
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        env_file:
            - .env.docker.db
        volumes:
            - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - backend
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
    web:
        build: .
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - .env.docker.web
        ports:
            - "8001:$PORT"
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - backend
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT myapp.wsgi
volumes:
    db:
networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

The Dockerfile builds just fine, and I can even see that `collectstatic` is running and collecting the appropriate files during the build. However, when the build is finished, the only evidence that `collectstatic` ran is an empty directory called `staticfiles`. If I run `collectstatic` again inside of my container, `collectstatic` works just fine, but since Heroku doesn't persist files created after the build stage, they disappear when my app restarts.

I found a few SO answers discussing how to get `collectstatic` to run inside a Dockerfile, but that's not my problem; my problem is that it does run, but the collected files don't show up in the container. Anyone have a clue what's going on?

**UPDATE:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71982071/6514229) did the trick. My `docker-compose.yml` was overriding the changes made by `collectstatic` with this line:

```
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
```

If, like me, you want to keep the bind mount for ease of local development (so that you don't need to re-build each time), you can edit the command for the web service as follows:

```
        command: bash -c "python -m manage collectstatic && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT myapp.wsgi"
```

Note that the image would have run just fine as-is had I pushed it to Heroku (since Heroku doesn't use the `docker-compose.yml` file), so this was just a problem affecting containers I created on my local machine.

Comment: How do you run your container when you start it?

Comment: I ran it from a docker-compose.yml file. I'll add the contents to my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the content of `/usr/src/app` in your container when you added the

```
volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
```

to your docker compose file.

Remove it since you already copied everything during the build.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick! Thank you for catching my rookie mistake.

Comment: If that helps, please consider making it as answered